# Type int on struct error

Tags: c++

I got the following struct:

```
struct Packet
{
    short PacketSize;
    short Type;
};

struct SizeValidity
{
    short SizeEnc;
};

struct SendEncSecureCode
{
    Packet header;
    short EncSecurityToken;
    int lTime;
    SizeValidity ending;
};
```

And on my code i want to get the size of the struct with the sizeof operator like this:

```
SendEncSecureCode sendpacket;
sendpacket.header.PacketSize = sizeof SendEncSecureCode;
```

Problem is i always get size 0x10 instead of 0x0C i am specting, so i change the INT type to DWORD and still the same problem, later i try with DWORD32 and still the same, the compiler is setting it as 8 bytes. I am working on VC11 Beta and the soft is aim to x86 not x64. Thanks

Comment: `sizeof SendEncSecureCode` needs brackets around `SendEncSecureCode` since it's a type. If that's compiling, I'd recommend changing it.

Comment: brackets arround the struct name gives me error that is not a variable...

Comment: possible duplicate of [structure padding and structure packing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the size you're expecting, you can tell the compiler to use 1-byte packing:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct Packet
{
    short PacketSize;
    short Type;
};

struct SizeValidity
{
    short SizeEnc;
};

struct SendEncSecureCode
{
    Packet header;
    short EncSecurityToken;
    int lTime;
    SizeValidity ending;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Please see http://vcfaq.mvps.org/lang/11.htm

Comment: Be aware that `#pragma pack` is non-standard.

Comment: For GCC use `__attribute__((packed))` just between the closing bracket and the semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

This is called padding. The compiler pads the space between the different members of the structure with zero bytes to better-align the members to addresses that can be read quicker by the CPU. You can (but should not unless you have a very good reason) override this behavior with [the `pack` pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
#pragma pack(push, 0)
struct {...};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

This forces the padding for this struct to be zero bytes. You can change the zero around.